# How do I make the shape created a circle?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from PIL import Image 
import time 
start = time.time() 
import random as r 
x = int(input("Enter the preferred width of your image:"))
y = int(input("Enter the preferred length of your image:"))
suggested = (x*y)
print("We suggest you use:",suggested,"pixels")
amount = int(input("How many pixels do you want to generate?"))
while amount > suggested:
    amount = int(input("Please choose the number suggested or smaller.     How many pixels do you want to generate?"))
numbers = []
numbs = (r.randint(0,255),r.randint(0,255),r.randint(0,255))
while len(numbers)<(amount):
    numbers.append(numbs)
    numbs = (r.randint(0,255),r.randint(0,255),r.randint(0,255))
print(numbers)
print('It took', time.time()-start, 'seconds')
im2 = Image.new('RGB', (x,y)) 
im2.putdata(numbers)
im2.show()
im2.save("out.png")
```

The code I have used puts three random numbers into one tuple, and then puts that tuple into a list. Each tuple is a pixel. The dimensions that the user enters will always make a straight shape x wide and y long, I want to make the shape round and have curved edges. How? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I played with your code and was able to add an open green circle and a blue filled circle.  Try it out:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import time 
import math
#
start = time.time() 
import random as r 
#x = int(input("Enter the preferred width of your image:"))
x = 100
#y = int(input("Enter the preferred length of your image:"))
y = 150
suggested = (x*y)
print("We suggest you use:",suggested,"pixels")
#amount = int(input("How many pixels do you want to generate?"))
amount = 15000
while amount > suggested:
    amount = int(input("Please choose the number suggested or smaller.     How many pixels do you want to generate?"))
numbers = []
numbs = (r.randint(0,255),r.randint(0,255),r.randint(0,255))
while len(numbers)<(amount):
    numbers.append(numbs)
    numbs = (r.randint(0,255),r.randint(0,255),r.randint(0,255))
print(numbers)
#
print('It took', time.time()-start, 'seconds')
im2 = Image.new('RGB', (x,y)) 
im2.putdata(numbers)
#-----------------------------------------------------------
numb_test = (255,0,0) # red circle
numb_test = (0,255,0) # green circle
radius_test = min(x,y) * 0.4
print "radius_test = " + str(radius_test)
x_center = x/2
y_center = y/2
angle_test = 0
print "pi = " + str(math.pi)
while angle_test < 360:
    angle_rads = angle_test * math.pi/180.0
    x_test = int(radius_test * math.cos(angle_rads)) + x_center
    y_test = int(radius_test * math.sin(angle_rads)) + y_center
    #print "x_test, y_test = " + str(x_test) + ", " + str(y_test)
    im2.putpixel((x_test, y_test),numb_test)
    angle_test += 1
#
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
draw.ellipse((20, 20, 40, 40), fill = 'blue', outline ='blue')
#-----------------------------------------------------------
im2.show()
im2.save("out.png")
```

Note that ImageDraw was also imported from PIL and math was imported.
I found the method to draw an ellipse described here: 
http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm